# Typescript abstract child inheritance typing problematic

Tags: typescript, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

How could I have "this.foo" as "Foo" in "Bar" class ?

```
abstract class AFoo {}

abstract class ABar {
    constructor(protected foo: AFoo) {}
}

class Foo extends AFoo {
    echoTest() {
        return 'test';
    };
}

class Bar extends ABar {
    constructor(foo: Foo) {
        super(foo)
    }

    write() {
        //Actually this line don't work cause this.foo is of AFoo type
        return this.foo.echoTest();
        //I want to avoid casting like this 
        //(<Foo>this.foo).echoTest();
    }
}
```

Expected the overloading of the constructor to induce the child type to the class

Comment: No, overriding (not overloading) the constructor does not mutate types.  You can make `ABar` generic or you can explicitly narrow the `foo` property of `Bar`; both ways are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6enrW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?